# Excel VBA to paste specified row into next blank cell

Tags: vba, excel

I've tried figuring this out but I'm stumped! Any help would be greatly received.

I've got two sheets, the first does all the workings and the second sheet is the UI one. In a nutshell, I want a macro that copies the data from 'Sheet 1' cells O5:P5 and pastes as a value into the next blank row on the sheet 'Generator'. I have headers in B6 and C6, so the code should be pasting into B7:C7, then B8:C8, etc. on the 'Generator' tab.

I've got the below code:

```
 Dim NextRow As Range
 Set NextRow = Range("B" & Sheets("Generator").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
 Sheet1.Range("O5:P5").Copy
 Generator.Activate
 NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Set NextRow = Nothing
```

The error I'm getting when I run this is Run-time '424': Object Required and this is on the "Generator.Activate" line. My VBA experience is very limited but any help would be fantastic.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try `Sheets("Generator").Activate`

Comment: That's worked, thank you!

Comment: You don't even need that line, the `Activate` command is in excess here.